Java: HTTP запрос URL с целевого IP
Возможно ли в приложении на Java перенаправлять HTTP запросы целевого URL на целевой IP, например, запрашивать ya.ru со 127.0.0.1. Внутренними средствами Java, не используя файл hosts (при одних условиях url запрашивается с оригинального Ip, при других- с локалхоста).
Возможно, использовать какой-то фейковый DNS-resolver?

Какой в этом вопросе вообще смысл? Уточните, что у вас не получается
